# OpenCV: not authorized to capture video

Tags: python, opencv, mac, камера

Использую старый макбук 2013 года, но с новой версией 13.4.1. И при работе с opencv-python не работает встроенная камера. Так же если подключить телефон как камеру, то в все равно не будет работать. Однако если запустить напрямую через терминал, то это может сработать хоть и не сразу. Пишу в VsCode, пробовал pycharm, ошибки такие же. Индекс камеры в VideoCapture также пробовал менять, не помогает.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    successful, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]